In SwiftUI how to disable interaction with Item row in List but allow interaction with element inside item?
I am having some Item inside List, Item row has some Button inside, when I click on it default blue border is coming and Interaction with button is not happening properly.
I can not change it to Scrollview as I am doing expand collaps thing with List row.
also both button got click at once on click on Item row
Don't want to use TapGuesture. See the Image, default blue border around List Item row.
       var body: some View {
            
         List {
           HStack {
            NavigationLink("First Button") {
            }
            .background(.red)
            Spacer(minLength: 20)
            
            NavigationLink("Second Button") {
            }
            .background(.orange)

        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)

          }
       }



@Sweeper I updated question, SpruceUI is used for predefined UI, foe ex. Instead of NavigationLink I used Row

@Sweeper Added minimal reproducible code, with Image

@Sweeper you are correct, I have removed button and only kept Navigation Link to navigate to other screen, But still getting default blue border as shown in image

@Sweeper Because of List selection, If I click  on row both buttons got clicked and unwanted blue selection appears which I don't want, How to remove that blue highlighted  selection

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
